# Chromedriver.exe has stopped working when run from cmd

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

We were trying to add some selenium scripts on Jenkins but whenever we gave the command I was receiving an error "Chromedriver.exe has stopped working".

I moved chromedriver to another location, such as C:, to test it and I found that if I manually doubleclick it from the folder is working fine.  But whenever I try to start it from the command prompt is giving me the error "Chromedriver.exe has stopped working".

Any ideas?

Environment: Windows 10 64bit

Comment: What command you are using to start Chromedriver ?? it should have been started at the time of creating instance of driver.

Comment: Just "chromedriver.exe"

Comment: And also tried "START chromedriver.exe" with this solution I manage to "open" the console of chromedriver but I get teh same error.

Comment: Thats what I am wondering why do you need to execute command, you just need to do:  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/XYZ/chromedriver.exe")); and create instance like driver = new ChromeDriver(options); thats it.

Comment: When I run it from Intellij is working perfectly.  Problem is happening only via cmd.  Since we need to run it through Jenkins and give the command from command prompt this is needed for me.  In some other machines we achieved this but not on mine.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue. In my case it was explicit .quit() missing. This was only case with 32-bit Python, 64-bit Python was working fine even without it.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
#do some work with the downloaded contents
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Indeed, it actually stops working when the script exits without a `browser.quit()`, *not* because of `browser.get()`! `browser.quit()` at the end of the script solved the issue.